# Why don't we have to work every non-Shabbos day?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, employment, aseres-hadibros, chol-weekday

We are told multiple times in the Torah

> ששת ימים תעבוד
>
> Six days you should work.

But many people do not actually work 6 days a week. For example, in the United States, Sunday is considered a weekend day, and many people do not attend work on that day. Indeed, many retired people hardly ever do any of these kinds of work. Are all of the people who do not attend work on Sunday, or at all, in error?!

Or perhaps this refers to all kinds of work like housework, homework, etc. Are people who don't do those things (or whatever is meant by *taavod*) every day in violation of the mitzvah?

I am leaving the topic of *melacha* aside for now because I would assume that if the verse were talking about it, it would use that word specifically.  I am aware that it also says:

> ששת ימים תעשה מלאכה

but I am assuming that is discussing a separate requirement. Is that an incorrect assumption?

Comment: Intentionally didn't tag with [tag:melacha-creative-work] because I'm not asking about that. Any other tagging help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not great at grammar but the tav prefix seems to indicate what one MAY do, not SHOULD do. The dibrot say "lo tisa et shem" as a statement of permission -- one MAY NOT take God's name in vain. Couldn't this statement then just be "on six days you MAY work"? BTW the http://bible.ort.org/books/Torahd5.asp?action=displayid&id=2062 translation has "can" and Chabad has "may"

Comment: @Danno, so _uvayom hash'vii tishbos_ means we *may* rest on the seventh?

Comment: @msh210 interestingly, when used in the "positive", chabad consistently translates as "may" but in the "negative" it translates as "shall" http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9884 . [those labels of negative and positive relate to the nature of the statement, not a clear use of positive or negative language] I only wonder if there is a grammatical subtlety at play here.

Comment: So an answer showing that the phrase is understood traditionally as referring to melacha would be satisfactory?

Comment: @DoubleAA That plus an explanation of why we don't have to do melacha every day besides Shabbos (or an explanation that we *do* have to) would be satisfactory.

Comment: @Danno sounds like [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) although does it really translate *matzot tocheilu* as "you *may* eat matzah"?

Comment: @Daniel it would be "shall" because that is a restrictive commandment in its nature (matzot to the exclusion of chametz). That is what I meant by "negative" in the earlier comment. When the law in question comes to limit by its nature, the tav is a shall (a circular argument by definition maybe, or a function of the prefix -- I don't know)

Comment: @Danno I don't think so. Lo ye'achel chametz is the restrictive commandment about not eating chametz. Matzot tocheilu I think is the positive commandment that one must eat matzah during Pesach.

Comment: @daniel the statement to eat matzah is implicitly tot he exclusion of chametz -- it is not that this is the makor for no chametz, but the nature of the statement is that it is dietarily restrictive. Look at the double lashon in Bereishit 2:16 -- you may (not shall) eat of all trees but there is still a restriction. By 2:17, the language is "shall not eat." Either that or the translations are (if not capricious) then arbitrary -- so why is this one "should" and not "may"?

Comment: I don't understand this: "I am assuming that is discussing a separate requirement. If that is an incorrect assumption, I'd like to know how we know?" You have made an assumption. But logic tells you it is incorrect. You are looking for a source that raises your concern and then explains why it is not a concern? Can you not be satisfied with, "That's now how the Pasuk is learned; it goes like this..."?

Comment: @SethJ Ok, I've edited.

Answer (score 2):

[Abarbanel](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40216&st=&pgnum=74) explains this verse - that one may work the other 6 days - not that one is required to work.

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_33655_43.pdf

Comment: Interesting. He says that it is permissible rather than required without giving a reason. And then he goes on to compare working 6 days to Hashem's creation of the world, which seems like support for requiring someone to work 6 days.

Comment: This is definitely the answer. I'm just surprised I can't find something really early like a midrash halacha saying "Sheshet Yamim - Eino Chovah Ella Reshut" or something like that.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Ramb"m states that one is required to work all 6 days. So, no lazy Friday's or Sundays.